# How to download a large file in Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

Well I wanna download large files (arround 200mb or more) in my devices (ios or Android) but on Cordova and FileTransfer plugin can only download less than 2mb otherwise it'll crash.

So how I can download large files?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library to making it possible to download larger files in the background

[cordova-plugin-background-download](https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download)

Comment: I did try with 5mb, 10mb, 50mb, 100mb and 512mb and it work :D
iOS 9+ and Android 7+